# Prevent need for the same select_related clause on multiple views in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given the following models...

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Activity(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

and these serializers...

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['user']


class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player = PlayerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ['player']
```

if I want to use django-rest-framework to list all the activities, I need to do something like this...

```
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Activity.objects.select_related("player__user") <--- this is needed because the activity serializer is going to serialize the player which has a user
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
```

That's all fine. But then, every time I write a new view which, at some level, uses PlayerSerializer, I'm going to have to remember to do the proper select_related clause in order to keep the number of DB lookups low.

I'm going to end up writing a lot of views which have the same select_related clauses (mine are actually a LOT more complicated than this example) and, if the PlayerSerializer ever changes, I'm going to need to remember to change all the view lookups.

This doesn't seem very DRY to me and I feel like there must be a better way to do it. Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe having a base parent class like:

```
class BaseViewset(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    SELECT_RELATED_FIELD = None  # for providing select related field in your queryset or maybe have a default value for this one (based on your use case)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.SELECT_RELATED_FIELD or not isinstance(self.SELECT_RELATED_FIELD, str):
            raise NotImplementedError("Ensure 'SELECT_RELATED_FIELD' is not empty/ Is instance of string")
        return super().get_queryset().select_related(self.SELECT_RELATED_FIELD)
```

And then use this parent class in all of your views instead of `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`:

```
class ActivityViewSet(BaseViewset):
    SELECT_RELATED_FIELD = "player__user"
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
```

would be a good start (in all views that you have `select_related` part).

Comment: But that way, I'll still have the select_related references in all of the views, no? You've just abstracted the actual call to the method.

Comment: that's true... but at least you're sure that you will override select related attribute.. otherwise it'll raise an exception... and as I mentioned before you can also have a default value for your select related part (views which have the same select_related clauses) to prevent repeating yourself... maybe you can play around with this `BaseView` and change it to your desired parent.